# Can't connect Database to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, web-hosting

I'm testing one of my work to live in a hosting to test the Database. When I created a Database in cPanel, it doesn't appear in phpmyadmin, I tried a bunch of things like installing MySQL Workbench and it just can't connect.

Comment: Are you sure you use proper permissions?

Comment: is this an account supplied by a hosting company, or you built your own cPanel install? If the former, contact the support channel for your hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably user permissions. In phpmyadmin, you provide basic connection settings to the database server. When logging in, you are actually connecting to the mysql server with the credentials you provided. Make sure that the user you are logging in with has at least reading rights on the newly created database.

Read more about granting permissions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, it just worked! I reseted all the settings and and deleted the DB I created then create the DB using MySQL DB Wizard, then open phpmyadmin, entered the credentials and viola! It worked.